Ok to use simple present tense after now? | "Now, we look at one more."
A British speaker, who teaches English on youtube, is telling about some usages for socializing. He gives examples, tells about differences, etc. Before he moves on to another one, he says:
"Now, we look at one more. We look at one more." 6 usefull english phrases (see:31:45-31:56)
He says it 2 times, so it is not accidental. I know he is going to write another example in a few seconds. So I wait for a sentence something like: "Now, we are going to look at one more. Or Now, we'll look at one more."
Instead, he starts the sentence with "Now" and then continues with simple present tense, which is of note-worthy for us non-native speakers.
I wonder whether it is just colloquial to use simple present tense for things that you are going to do in a few seconds/minutes.?

Radio and especially television correspondents frequently sprinkle their reports with loud "Now" exclamations, as if to mark a new paragraph (or just to keep their audience's attention). What follows is often delivered in the present tense as the most suitable to cover continuing events.


And now we {do this}.

When  someone is leading an audience along a path, of whatever nature, in a presentation, the present tense is often used.
Maybe that's why we call it a presentation. :-)

Does it mean something like "And now, let's do this."?

Yes, but it is an invitation to the audience only on a pro forma basis. It is actually a statement to orient the audience in regard to the next step in the presentation.

When I listened to the audio, what stood out to me was the pause after Now. From a transcript perspective the pause acts like a full stop. So it's not...

Now we look at one more.

But...

Now. We look at one more.

To get the flavour of this distinction, imagine him saying this:

Now we turn our attention to the final example.

The present tense therefore is used because it's describing the looking that happens or begins at that particular moment.
Note that the other possible sentences suggested in the OP are equally good. This sentence is not the only right way, but it's certainly natural and normal.
